# markdownでテーブルが作れない。

Tags: markdown

下記urlのwikiページにてmarkdown表記をしていたのですが、テーブル表示ができず困っております。

http://e-sports.tokyo
(上記ページでお好きなようにeditして頂いて構いません。)

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

markdownのテーブル表記は下記のようにすることで表示できるかと思っていたのですが間違っていますでしょうか？

|test1|test2|test3|
|---|---|---|
|hoge|fuga|pugya-|

あれ・・・
ここ(stackoverflow)でもテーブル表示ができていない・・・。

markdownでテーブル表示をさせる方法をご存じの方いらっしゃいましたらご助言頂けませんでしょうか？

よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: markdownの仕様(http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax)
ではTableはサポートされていないようです．Githubとかでは拡張ということでTableをサポートしているようです．このサイト(http://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables)ではHTMLの<Table>タグを使うことを提案しています．

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます！サポートされていないのでしたか・・・。知りませんでした。

Comment: gollum に `GitHub Flavored Markdown` を導入してみてはいかがでしょうか。`gem install github-markdown`

Comment: argus様 回答ありがとうございます！おっしゃるとおりにやりましたところ、無事にテーブルが出来ました！

Answer (score 6, accepted):

表を表現できるのは、"Markdown Extra" などと呼ばれているMarkdownを拡張したマークアップです。
Markdownでは直接`table`タグを使うしかありません。

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>test1</th>
        <th>test2</th>
        <th>test3</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>hoge</td>
        <td>fuga</td>
        <td>pugya</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

ただし、どのようなHTMLタグを許すかはサイトによります。
例えばここ(StackOverflow)では`table`は不可のようです。
(参考:  [表形式用のmarkdown記法はないのでしょうか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2022/))

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
tableタグは普通に使えましたので、あきらめて table タグを使って見ようと思います。